# How to import *just* a specific operator from another module?

Tags: swift

I need to use a particular protocol and an operator from a module A in my project in module B. However I cannot import the whole module since there are components in A with the same name as those in B, causing ambiguity. The solution to this is simple, to just import the particular protocol.

```
// Module B

import protocol A.SomeProtocol // Works perfectly
```

However, I am not being able to import the specific operator from A. I have tried:

```
// Module B

import func A.&&  // Expected module name in import declaration
import operator A.&&  // A is considered to be an identifier, not an operator
```

How can I go about importing the specific operator for use in this case?

Comment: `import protocol A.SomeProtocol // Works perfectly` For real? I've never head of this.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: https://nshipster.com/import/#importing-individual-declarations

Comment: I cannot test it currently: Does `import func A.(&&)` work?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#grammar_import-kind

Comment: @MartinR I tried using import `func Rubin.(&&)` however this fails with the error `Expected identifier in import declaration`

Comment: For now I have created a wrapper in module A and imported that. This does seem to highlight a tiny limitation the language it seems.